# iOS reading data from server regularly

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, ipad-2

I need to create a iOS app where the app has to continuously check for the updates from the server(may be every 30 secs). But only when the app is running on the foreground.
I know this will drain the battery, but this will run on a environment where there's no internet. So we can't use push notifications.

Only option I can think of is sending a request to the server every 30 secs or so and get the updates. What is the best way to do this? Using NSTimer and NSURLConnection or any other better approaches?

Also if I use a timer, when the app goes to the background will it pause and will it start running as it comes to the foreground again? Is there a chance that app get killed while its on background?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. If there is no internet, how are you going to communicate with the server?

Comment: Everything is inside a LAN. so we connect to the server locally.

Comment: Ah you are right. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to setup a separate object that manages these operations on a background thread. Then in your app delegate, when

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

is called, have this special object stop all of it's synchronizing and clean up anything it needs to.

Then when:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

gets called as the app gets active again, signal your object to query / poll on its background thread again.

Your custom object could have an interface like this

```
@interface PollingObject : NSObject
{
   NSTimer* _timer;
   NSUinteger _interval;
   BOOL _cancel;
   BOOL _isPolling;
   dispatch_queue_t _pollQueue;
}
- (void)startPolling;
- (void)stopPolling;
@end
```

The implementation can be something like this:

```
@implementation PollingObject : NSObject

- (id)init
{
   if (self = [super init])
   {
      _interval = 1; // 1 second interval
      _cancel = NO; // default to NO
      _isPolling = NO; // default to NO

      // init your background queue
      _pollQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.yourconame.yourappname.pollQueue", NULL);
   }
   return self;
}

- (void)heartbeat
{
   if (_cancel)
   {
      // stop the timer
      [_timer invalidate];
      _isPolling = NO;
      return;
   }

   // Runs the polling method ONCE on a background queue
   dispatch_async(_pollQueue, ^{
       [self pollingMethod];
   });
}

- (void)pollingMethod
{
   // Do actual network polling work here...but only run it once. (don't loop)
}

- (void)startPolling
{
   _cancel = NO;
   if (_isPolling)
   {
      NSLog(@"Already polling");
      return;
   }

   // schedule the method heartbeat to run every second
   _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:_interval target:self selector:@selector(heartbeat) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)stopPolling
{
   // we set the flag here and the next second the heartbeat will stop the timer
   _cancel = YES;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks. So what I have to do is create a thread using  GCD and put a timer inside it and stop it in  applicationWillResignActive and start back in applicationDidBecomeActive? dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ nstimer = .... });

Comment: Well the timer should be outside of the GCD queue and it should be setup to run a method every interval. But that method should be also checking for a cancel flag of some sort so it knows when to stop the timer or run the polling method within a separate GCD or NSOperation queue.

Comment: added more example code. Don't just copy/paste it though. Try to understand it.

Comment: Thanks valheru for your help and code. I understood it and I created a project with the help of that code. But now my problem is as Joseph mention in the other answer and comments I can do this jus using the NSTimer. Is there any advantage in doing it like this or is it ok to just use the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions? I tested both and both seems to work alike. Thanks

Comment: @Madhu - the truth is, for optimal OOP paradigm development, you don't want things laying loosely around in your appDelegate. Creating separate objects that encapsulate their data and functionality is much better for readability and extensibility. as for application:didFinishLaunching, this only handles when an app starts up, not when it goes into the background. Best to properly clean up the polling instead of just letting it all get killed.

Comment: Thanks valheru. Thats what I also thought, since application:didFinishLaunching is only for app start. But when I tested, by adding the NSTimer there, when it goes to background and and come back to foreground, the timer starts again. And everything seemed Ok. That's why I was confused whether to use this or that.

Answer (score 1):

> Using NSTimer and NSURLConnection or any other better approaches?

My first thought was also to use NSTimer and NSURLConnection.

> Also if I use a timer, when the app goes to the background will it pause and will it start running as it comes to the foreground again?

Yes, it will. It doesn't exactly pause, but based on my testing in the simulator, the effect is similar. Let's say the timer is set to go off at 00:00:00, 00:00:30, 00:00:60, ... and you background the app at 00:00:15 and resume it at 00:00:45. The timer that was supposed to fire at 00:00:30 fires immediately when you resume (at 00:00:45), and the next firing (at 00:00:60) and subsequent firings are back on schedule.

> Is there a chance that app get killed while its on background?

Yes, there is. But if you start the timer whenever the app launches, this shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Thanks for the details. So in order to start the timer when the app comes to foreground and to stop it when going to background, I'll have to do something similar to the other answer by 'valheru'. Is that correct?

Comment: Actually an `NSTimer` doesn't fire when an app is backgrounded, so you don't need to manually stop it. You could send message to start a repeating timer in `-application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and then forget about it.

Comment: Ok thanks. But will it start back automatically, when the app comes to foreground again?

Comment: Yes exactly, it will start again automatically when the app comes to the foreground again (you should set `repeats:YES` when you create your scheduled timer). To confirm this yourself you could `NSLog` the method that the `NSTimer` calls when fired.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Rocket real-time networking which looks easy to setup through AFNetworking 2.0.

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-2.0-Migration-Guide

See the last part of this wiki. I have not used it but it would be something I would try if I had your requirements.

Comment: Thanks, do you mean here is to use a socket based approach where server can send the notification to the app instead of doing polling?